# Parsing string with fromjson and collapsing into the parent in JQ

Tags: json, jq, fromjson

I am attempting to parse out the following json array below. The activities object is a string and I have successfully been able to parse it out with the following in jq.

```
[
 {
    "id": 101,
    "created_at": "1987-10-12 03:20:22.903",
    "updated_at": "1987-10-12 01:20:36.019",
    "activities": "{\"hero\": \"batman\", \"weapon\": \"sword\", \"ts\": null, \"remote\": \"1\",\"game\": \"joker\", \"image\": \"bold\"}"
 },
 {   
    "id": 102,
    "created_at": "2022-10-12 11:20:22.903724",
    "updated_at": "2022-10-12 11:20:36.019043",
    "activities": "{\"hero\": \"superman\", \"weapon\": \"cape\", \"ts\": null, \"remote\": \"2\",\"game\": \"batman\", \"image\": \"kind\"}"
  }
]
```

The following command allows me to parse out the string object but I haven't quite figured out how to get it back into the original array.

`jq '.[].activities | fromjson?' test.json`

Output:

```
{
  "hero": "batman",
  "weapon": "sword",
  "ts": null,
  "remote": "1",
  "game": "joker",
  "image": "bold"
}
{
  "hero": "superman",
  "weapon": "cape",
  "ts": null,
  "remote": "2",
  "game": "batman",
  "image": "kind"
}
```

I tried several variances of the += and |= operators to add back to the original without any luck.

`jq '.[].activities |= fromjson? | select( . != "")'` 
Bypassed any empty values with the select command.

This yields no results for the activities object when I run it. It brings the original id, created_at, and updated_at forward but nothing else.

Appreciate any help you can offer. Thanks guys.

Preferred Output

```
[
 {
    "id": 101,
    "created_at": "1987-10-12 03:20:22.903",
    "updated_at": "1987-10-12 01:20:36.019",
    "hero": "batman",
    "weapon": "sword",
    "ts": null,
    "remote": "1",
    "game": "joker",
    "image": "bold"
  },
  {
    "id": 102,
    "created_at": "2022-10-12 11:20:22.903724",
    "updated_at": "2022-10-12 11:20:36.019043",
    "hero": "superman",
    "weapon": "cape",
    "ts": null,
    "remote": "2",
    "game": "batman",
    "image": "kind"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should be enough:

```
map(del(.activities) + (.activities | fromjson))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jmySS6FybFf)</sup>

Comment: Even shorter, clever! I forgot that `.` is fed into both operands of `+` allowing you to delete and parse at the same time, then merge both resulting objects.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a starting point, assigning a real JSON object to the activities key:

```
map(.activities |= fromjson)
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 101,
    "created_at": "1987-10-12 03:20:22.903",
    "updated_at": "1987-10-12 01:20:36.019",
    "activities": {
      "hero": "batman",
      "weapon": "sword",
      "ts": null,
      "remote": "1",
      "game": "joker",
      "image": "bold"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 102,
    "created_at": "2022-10-12 11:20:22.903724",
    "updated_at": "2022-10-12 11:20:36.019043",
    "activities": {
      "hero": "superman",
      "weapon": "cape",
      "ts": null,
      "remote": "2",
      "game": "batman",
      "image": "kind"
    }
  }
]
```

And to merge the activities sub-object into its parent object, while deleting the old property:

```
map(. + (.activities | fromjson) | del(.activities))
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 101,
    "created_at": "1987-10-12 03:20:22.903",
    "updated_at": "1987-10-12 01:20:36.019",
    "hero": "batman",
    "weapon": "sword",
    "ts": null,
    "remote": "1",
    "game": "joker",
    "image": "bold"
  },
  {
    "id": 102,
    "created_at": "2022-10-12 11:20:22.903724",
    "updated_at": "2022-10-12 11:20:36.019043",
    "hero": "superman",
    "weapon": "cape",
    "ts": null,
    "remote": "2",
    "game": "batman",
    "image": "kind"
  }
]
```